# rename files in a folder based on a text file ordering

Tags: powershell, rename, powershell-3.0

I have a ton of files but they are ordered randomly as they were generated all at the same time.

I have a text file with the names of the files in the correct order.
I want to rename the files in the folder to follow the text file like this:

if the file is first on the list in the text file I want to rename it to 1, the second file should be renamed 2.. then 3... etc

I know I can do something like `Rename-Item -Path "c:\daily_file.txt" -NewName "monday_file.txt"`

but how do I follow the text file ordering

text file looks like this:

```
car.json
carjkd.json
farmlyar.json
farmlayr2.json
```

and the folder has these all these files just randomly ordered because they were all created at the same time. the folder has all these files. then i want the file car.json to be named 1 carjkd.json to be renamed 2, farmlyar.json to be renamed 3...etc

Comment: Can you update your question to provide a sanitized example of your text file, to include a before and after for expected results? Also, which PowerShell version are you running this on? Remove the tags and only leave the appropriate one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you want something like this:

```
Get-Content -Path "C:\Path\To\file.txt" | 
    ForEach-Object -Begin { [ref]$i = 1 } -Process {
        Get-Item -Path "C:\Path\To\Jsons\$_" | Rename-Item -NewName { "{0}{1}"-f $i.Value++, $_.Extension } -WhatIf
}
```

This will rename your files that have the same name in your text file in numerical order, starting at 1.

---

*Remove the `-WhatIf` common/safety parameter when you've dictated those are the results you're after*.